# Adding numbers within a certain range. How?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So far I cant figure out how to do it. It only adds the start and the end of the range, it doesnt add the numbers within the range or I think its not what I input as a range that it adds but instead it adds the number between x an y.

I am trying to add numbers between a certain range of array.

```
int[] range = new int[10];

for (int x = 0; x < range.length; x++) {
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    range[x]  = in.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Enter the numbers for the start and end of the range. ");
int start = in.nextInt();
int end = in.nextInt();

start = range[start];
end = range[end];

for(; start < end; end = end -1) {
    start =end+ start;
}

System.out.println(start);
```

Sorry if the question has already been asked.

Comment: Think about it - you're adding up all of these numbers. Where do you store them? You need another variable to store the total of all of the numbers.

Comment: `start =end+ start`. In effect you are overriding the value of the start. You should use another variable like sum and add sum to each index of array as you increment in the for loop

Answer (score 3):

Try doing a less exotic loop. Something like this should do it.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=start; i <= end; i++){
    sum = sum + range[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, first thing:

```
start = range[start];
end = range[end];
```

When you initialize array you make user to input numbers, and what you want for a range - not numbers, but **indexes**. And be sure - you will forget what you tried to do with this code in a month, so you have to make it more readable - make additional variable for the result (and comments ofc).
So that's how i see a code that will work fine:

```
int start = in.nextInt();
int end = in.nextInt();
int result=0;
for(;start <= end; start++){
    result += range[start];
//any other operations with numbers incide your range
}
System.out.println(result);
```